# Mongo Query Nested Field Values with two-level unknown parent keys

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

We use MongoDB to store time-series sensor data similar to the schema designed shown in https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/schema-design-for-time-series-data-in-mongodb

We do get good performance on data queries through time periods. 
Explanation on the our schema design: 
**"v"** is the parent key of sensor readings, the time is converted into nested array using Minutes and Seconds. We use **"m"**(Minute) as sub-parent key, then **"s"**(Second) as sub-key of minute reading. The sensor readings are located at the **"s"** level with **field1**, **field2**, ...,**field10** as the sensor data values.

Now we are trying to implement some data analysis facilities and looking to query the data through sensor data reading values.  Is there an efficient way of querying from data without using nested for loop in the query?

for example:

1. Items that have sensor reading: **"field1">2**
2. Items that have sensor reading: **"field1">2** and  **"field3">5**

Thanks a million.

The records look like the examples below.

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("5a5dd49f74bbaefd1ac89fc8"),
   "c_id": "1017",
   "c_id_s": NumberInt(1017),
   "c_t": NumberInt(1516096800),
   "type": "hour",
   "v": {
     "m1": {
       "s54": {
         "field1": 7.373158,
         "entry_id": NumberInt(4635),
         "field3": 0.19,
         "field2": NumberInt(88) 
      } 
    },
     "m31": {
       "s54": {
         "field1": 5.981918,
         "entry_id": NumberInt(4637),
         "field3": 0.04 
      },
       "s55": {
         "field2": NumberInt(89),
         "entry_id": NumberInt(4639),
         "field5": NumberInt(-67) 
      } 
    } 
  },
   "entry_id": NumberInt(4639) 
}, 
{
   "_id": ObjectId("5a5dd1a174bbaefd1ac89fc1"),
   "c_id": "1024",
   "c_id_s": NumberInt(1024),
   "c_t": NumberInt(1516096800),
   "type": "hour",
   "v": {
     "m3": {
       "s22": {
         "field3": 210.479996,
         "entry_id": NumberInt(30297) 
      },
       "s23": {
         "field1": 3.271534,
         "entry_id": NumberInt(30300),
         "field8": 7.1875,
         "field2": NumberInt(94) 
      } 
    },
     "m8": {
       "s23": {
         "field3": 150.639999,
         "entry_id": NumberInt(30304),
         "field1": 2.948425,
         "field8": 7.125,
         "field2": NumberInt(94) 
      } 
    },
     "m13": {
       "s23": {
         "field3": 99.799995,
         "entry_id": NumberInt(30308),
         "field1": 2.849621,
         "field8": 7.0625,
         "field2": NumberInt(95) 
      } 
    },
     "m18": {
       "s23": {
         "field3": 59.099998,
         "entry_id": NumberInt(30312),
         "field1": 2.681393,
         "field8": 6.9375,
         "field2": NumberInt(95) 
      } 
    },
     "m19": {
       "s8": {
         "field5": NumberInt(-87),
         "entry_id": NumberInt(30313) 
      } 
    } 
  },
   "entry_id": NumberInt(30313) 
}
```

Comment: Please give us an example of how you would want the returned document to look like.

Comment: The returned document can be the whole documents that match the conditions

Comment: @dnickless The returned document can be the whole documents that match the conditions

Comment: Currently I am using this way, but its slow: 
{$and:[{c_id: "415"},{
    $where: function() {
        for(var key in this.v) {
            for (var subKey in this.v[key])
 {
        if(this.v[key][subKey].field1>2)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
  }
  return false;
}
    }
    ]
}

Comment: What is your mongo server version ?

Comment: @Veeram version is 3.2.16

Comment: @leon did you reach anything? I am facing a similar issue.

Comment: @omarsafwany not really....

Comment: could you share with us what you have tried and/or want to improve? That would be easier to try to improve or try other solutions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Map reduce allows you to process named keys but aggregation is the way to go for efficient queries.

You have to model the data as array of embedded documents for aggregation framework.

I've provided you two options. You can test them out for your dataset and see which one works better for you.

Something like

```
"v":[
  {
    "minute":1,
    "seconds":[
      {
        "second":54,
        "data":{
         "field1":7.373158,
         "entry_id":4635,
         "field3":0.19,
         "field2":88
       }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "minute":2,
    "seconds":...
  }
]
```

Now you can easily query for items that have sensor reading: "field1">2.

```
db.col.aggregate(
  [{"$match":{"v.seconds.data.field1":{"$gt":2}}},
   {"$unwind":"$v"}, 
   {"$match":{"v.seconds.data.field1":{"$gt":2}}},
   {"$unwind":"$v.seconds"}, 
   {"$match":{"v.seconds.data.field1":{"$gt":2}}},
   {"$project":{"data":"$v.seconds.data"}}]
)
```

Alternatively, You can split the documents by minute. Something like

```
"v":[
  {
    "second":1,
    "data":{
       "field1":7.373158,
       "entry_id":4635,
       "field3":0.19,
       "field2":88
     }
  },
  {
     "second":2,
     "data":...
  }
]
```

You can now query like ( with index on v.data.field1 )

```
db.col.aggregate(
  [{"$match":{"v.data.field1":{"$gt":2}}},
   {"$unwind":"$v"}, 
   {"$match":{"v.data.field1":{"$gt":2}}},
   {"$project":{"data":"$v.data"}}]
)
```

You can query items that have sensor reading: "field1">2 and "field3">5

Using first structure

```
db.col.aggregate(
  [{"$match":{"v":{"$elemMatch":{"seconds": {$elemMatch:{"field1":{$gt":2},"field3":{$gt":5}}}}}}},
  {"$unwind":"$v"}, 
    {"$match":{"v.seconds": {$elemMatch:{"field1":{$gt":2},"field3":{$gt":5}}}}},
  {"$unwind":"$v.seconds"}, 
  {"$project":{"data":"$v.seconds.data"}}]
)
```

Using second structure

```
db.col.aggregate(
  [{"$match":{"v.data":{$elemMatch:{"field1":{$gt":2},"field3":{$gt":5}}}}},
  {"$unwind":"$v"}, 
  {"$match":{"v.data.field1":{"$gt":2},"v.data.field3":{"$gt":5} }},
  {"$project":{"data":"$v.data"}}]
)
```

Mongo Update 3.6

`$match` with `$expr` which accepts aggregation expression.

`$gt > 0` - aggregation expression to check where the sum of all matching seconds criteria in a minute is greater than 0

`$objectToArray` to convert the named keys into key value pair followed by `$filter` seconds on input criteria and output no of matching seconds record.

```
db.testcol.aggregate(
{"$match":{
  "$expr":{
    "$gt":[
      {"$sum":{
        "$map":{
          "input":{"$objectToArray":"$v"},
          "as":"secondsofminute",
          "in":{
            "$size":{
              "$filter":{
                "input":{"$objectToArray":"$$secondsofminute.v"},
                "as":"seconds",
                "cond":{"$gt":["$$seconds.v.field2",2]}
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }},
    0]
  }
}})
```

Mongo Update 3.4 - Replace `$expr` with `$redact`

```
db.col.aggregate(
 {"$redact":{
  "$cond":{
    "if":{
      "$gt":[
        {"$sum":{
          "$map":{
            "input":{"$objectToArray":"$v"},
            "as":"secondsofminute",
            "in":{
              "$size":{
                "$filter":{
                  "input":{"$objectToArray":"$$secondsofminute.v"},
                  "as":"seconds",
                  "cond":{"$gt":["$$seconds.v.field2",2]}
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }},
        0]
    },
   "then":"$$KEEP",
   "else":"$$PRUNE"
  }
}})
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but currently we don't want to change the data storage structure as the system is live already.  There are also pros and cons with your proposed structure, e.g. Sorting data by minutes and seconds will be slower.

Comment: Np. I've added both 3.6 & 3.4 version update. For lower version you've to use $where/map-reduce

Comment: we provide real-time data browsing services to our customers, map-reduce is not really feasible

Comment: I'm afraid you don't have many options for versions lower than 3.4. Is server upgrade an option  for you ?

Comment: Upgrade is possible, what are the options for the queries?

Comment: I've already added possible aggregation options for 3.4 and 3.6. Did you get a chance to review ?

Comment: I want to keep the current schema structure. Do we have any option using my schema?

Comment: Yes that is what [2nd](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/48285493/2) and [3rd](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/48285493/4) revisions are. Changes are at the bottom of solution which doesn't need any schema changes.

Comment: Did the 3.4, 3.6 solution didn't work for you ? Is that not what you are looking for ? You can also enumerate keys (minute/ seconds pair) and $or'ing then together to produce the criteria for your search.

Comment: Hi @Veeram  I tried your Mongo 3.4 version aggregate, it didn't work. No results were given

Comment: I've verified the query again  against he data that you've provided. It gives me the expected result. Can I see your query pls ?

Comment: Hi Veeram, I evaluated the query again, it did work. I probably did something wrong at the first stage. Thanks a lot